# Array from form - Wordpress Metadata

Tags: php, arrays, forms, wordpress, metadata

I got a custom post type, with a form for storing some data (name, url) to display in a template.

What I want to know is **how can I store those values in an array**?

An example of my code:

```
<? function files_metadata(){  
        global $post; 
        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);  
        $name = $custom["name"][0];
        $url = $custom["url"][0];

        echo '<input type="hidden" name="files_metadata" id="files_metadata" value="' .wp_create_nonce('files_m'). '" />'; ?>  

<label>Name: </label><br/>
<input id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
<label>Url: </label><br/>
<input id="url" name="url" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" />

<? function save_meta_files($post_id) {  
        if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['files_metadata'], 'files_m')) return $post_id;
        if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return $post_id;

        update_post_meta($post_id, "name", $_POST["url"]);   
        update_post_meta($post_id, "url", $_POST["url"]); 
    }  

add_action('save_post', 'save_meta_files'); ?>
```

To this I want to add something like...

```
$url = $custom["url"][0];
$url2 = $custom["url"][1];
$url3 = $custom["url"][2];

<input id="url" name="url[0]" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<input id="url2" name="url[1]" value="<?php echo $url2; ?>" />
<input id="url3" name="url[2]" value="<?php echo $url3; ?>" />

update_post_meta($post_id, "url", $_POST["url"][0]); 
update_post_meta($post_id, "url2", $_POST["url"][1]); 
update_post_meta($post_id, "url3", $_POST["url"][2]);
```

...but that actually works...

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I want to store values in arrays, like the ones in the second code box, but the problem that I got is that the values are not stored with the wordpress code, I guess something is wrong with it... can you please check it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A passed array will be serialized into a string: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta

```
update_post_meta(
    $post_id,
    'files_metadata',
    array(
        'name1' => $_POST['name1'],
        'url1' => $_POST['url1']
        'name2' => $_POST['name2'],
        'url2' => $_POST['url2']
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but for more that I try, I couldn't get right the other two where is  
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$name = $custom["files_metadata"][0];  
and  <input id="name" name="files_metadata[0]" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />, what could be the right way to put it?

Comment: Take a look at the structure of the output of `var_dump(get_post_custom($post->ID));`.